# Bootcamp: My Mac Only Boots into macOS No Matter What Partition I Choose

Tags: bootcamp, partition, startup

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro 15 inch running 10.13.5 and a bootcamp partition of Windows 10. I cannot boot into windows unless I select the windows partition from system preferences and restart from there.

If I try and hold down the option key on restart, Startup Manager opens but no matter which partition I click, it boots into macOS. It will not let me boot into windows this way.

Is there any way to fix Startup Manager/boot into windows?

Edit: [Video on what is happening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSB4j8QsMVo)

Comment: +1 for the hand motion at the end :) (And for the good question)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just super annoyed at this problem and there doesn't seem to be a fix for it :(

Comment: Also experiencing same issue with a 2016 MacBook Pro with TouchBar. Everything was fine till a few days ago. I’ve used bootcamp with APFS for months before the issue appeared.

Comment: I just updated to the beta of Mojave and am having the issue still

Comment: I think the issue may be with windows itself. I recently did no updates on the mac but I definitely did some on windows. Maybe it messed up some booting info and Startup Manager gets confused.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, with a 2016 MBPtb! I've created a question on the apple support forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8447912

Comment: @JoeBauer I would look at it but I don't have access to it :P

There have been a few people popping up that have the same issue. I'm gonna try and boot into windows to see if there was another update that might have fixed it. Apple hasn't released anything in a while.

Comment: @JoeBauer yeah, the link is bad

Comment: @R.Gillie my mac seems to have fixed itself today...

Comment: @edo42 Mine is finicky, I just tried it and it didn't work, but earlier it worked flawless. I'm at a loss on what's causing this / how to fix

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK High Sierra already "introduced" APFS. The Bootcamp partition is formatted NTFS, I thought. If you set the startup disk to macOS in Settings (while in macOS), then, when you startup holding the Alt key, the boot window should let you choose between the two partitions. I cannot check now since I am a long way from base.
I am not sure when Startup disk is set to the Bootcamp partition, everything will work correctly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mac's problem,after having this problem,i tried to boot ubuntu on my 2016mbp,and it boots into macOS too.But now we have 10.14 beta3,it seems there is no general issues about this.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffered this problem just now, for me the solution seemed to be resetting my macs PRAM by holding command + option + p + r on startup. After doing this bootcamp booted into windows then windows said it had to do some disk repair (dont know why) but I'm grateful I managed to get it sorted without too much issue. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Which file system is on your HD? HFS or APFS? if you updated via the App Store, and you have an ssd, the update automatically changed your file system to APFS, for supported Macs. Run Disk Utility, it will say, also the "About this Mac," will say. The two don’t mix.

Comment: It is APFS, but it was working fine a little while ago. Is there any way to fix/change file systems so it will work?

Comment: *The two don't mix* - Do you mean APFS and Windows or Journaled HFS+ and APFS? If you mean JHFS+ and APFS, then this answer does not have anything to do with this question. If you mean APFS and Windows, then, well, I have both macOS with APFS and Windows (and Mojave with APFS) installed at the same time, and I am not having any issues. Maybe you need to install it manually without Bootcamp Assistant. That's what I did.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not understanding your answer or what you mean by "The two don't mix". It worked before, but now it's not, and I haven't touched anything at all relating to file systems. I have my mac using APFS and have bootcamp with a 100gb partition for windows. I edited my original post with a link to what is going on.